# Prove that $P(A) \cup P(B) \cup P(A \cap B) \subset P(A \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove

> $P(A) \cup P(B) \cup P(A \cap B) \subset P(A \cup B)$,

and I'm having a little trouble with it. I've thought about using equivalences, but it seems like that would get messy and confusing really fast. I'm new to set theory, so I'd appreciate any help I can receive on this problem.

Comment: Pick an element of the set on the left-hand-side (i.e., let $X \in P(A) \cup P(B) \cup P(A\cap B)$), then show it's in the set on the right-hand-side. There will be 3 cases to consider, depending on whether $X \in P(A)$, $X \in P(B)$, or $X \in P(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $A\subset C$ then $P(A)\subset P(C)$ and if $A\subset C$, $B\subset C$ then $(A\cup B)\subset C$.

Now for any sets $A$ and $B$, we have $A\subset A\cup B$, $B\subset A\cup B$,  and $A\cap B\subset A\cup B$. So $$P(A)\subset P(A\cup B), P(B)\subset P(A\cup B), P(A\cap B)\subset P(A\cup B)$$ and hence $P(A)\cup P(B)\cup P(A\cap B)\subset P(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C\in P(A)$. Then $C\subset A$. But $A\subset A\cup B$ implying that $C\subset A\cup B$ and so, $C\in P(A\cup B)$. Thus, $P(A)\subset P(A\cup B)$. Similarly, $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$ are subsets of $P(A\cup B)$. Thus, 
$$P(A)\cup P(B)\cup P(A\cap B)\subset P(A\cup B).$$